# Using AsyncTask in PreferenceFragment

Tags: android, android-asynctask, sharedpreferences, preferencefragment

I am tring to create a sharedpreference to save some authentication info to a third party service. In my preferences.xml there is a login and password fields but i would like to check if the values are valid (authenticate) when edited. What would be a good approach?

So far, i have this:

on create

```
findPreference("sync_service_enabled").setOnPreferenceChangeListener(this);
findPreference("sync_service_user").setOnPreferenceChangeListener(this);
findPreference("sync_service_pwd").setOnPreferenceChangeListener(this);
```

my listener

```
public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
    if (preference.getKey().contains("sync_service")){
     new AuthenticationRemoteAsyncTask(this.getActivity(), user, password, service).execute();
    }
    return true;
```

I also need to save a token generated by the remote service so I need to wait for the aynstask to be finished.

Any sugestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved my problem criating a custom dialogpreference. I Replaced the positive button onclicklistener so it dont close the dialog automatically and start my remote task. The asynctask will notify my preferencedialog after success and only then I close the dialog.

CODE

```
@Override
protected void showDialog(Bundle state) {
    super.showDialog(state);
    ...
    positiveButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    negativeButton.setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

onclick handler

```
public void onClick(View view){
    this.result = null;
    if(view.getId() == positiveButton.getId()) {
        String password = textPassword.getText().toString();
        String user = textLogin.getText().toString();

        new AuthenticationTask(getContext(),user, password)
            .notify(this).execute();
    }else{
        alertDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

check the result before close

```
@Override
protected void onDialogClosed(boolean positiveResult) {
    super.onDialogClosed(positiveResult);

    if (result != null) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getEditor();
        editor.putString("sync_service_token",result);
        editor.commit();
    }
}
```

AuthenticationTask is a custom class that wrapp all the async stuff and call a notify method.